# Query in PHP wont pull data that is already in the system

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to check if a given email exists in the database, but the query returned is null and I'm not sure why.

I've tried manually inputting the email address as recorded in the table but its still not working.

user.php :

```
function emailExists()
{

    $query = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, access_level, password, 
status from " . $this->table_name . " where email = ?";

    //prepare this query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
```

login.php :

```
//get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

//initialize objects
$user = new User($db);

//check if email and password are in the database
$user->email=$_POST['email'];

//check if email exists, also get user details using this emailExists() method
$email_exists = $user->emailExists();
```

Database class:

```
class Database{

    // specify your own database credentials
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "games_for_sale";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    public $conn;

    // get the database connection
    public function getConnection(){

        $this->conn = null;

        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
        }catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

User class:

```
class User{
    //database connection
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "users";

    //object properties
    public $id;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $email;
    public $contact_number;
    public $address;
    public $password;
    public $access_level;
    public $access_code;
    public $status;
    public $created;
    public $modified;

    //constructor
    public function _construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    //check if given email exist in the database
    function emailExists()
    {

        $query = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, access_level, password, status from " . $this->table_name . " where email = ?";

        //prepare this query
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        //sanitize
        $this->email = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));

        //bind given email value
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->email);

        //execute the query
        $stmt->execute();

        //get number of rows
        $num = $stmt->rowCount();

        //if email exists, assign values to object properties for easy access and use for php sessions
        if ($num > 0) {

            //get record details / values
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            //assign values to object properties
            $this->id = $row['id'];
            $this->firstname = $row['firstname'];
            $this->lastname = $row['lastname'];
            $this->access_level = $row['access_level'];
            $this->password = $row['password'];
            $this->status = $row['status'];

            //return true because email exists in the database
            return true;
        }

        //retturn false if email does not exist in the database
        return false;
    }

}
```

The error I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   null in user.php:34 Stack trace: 
>   #0 login.php(34): User->emailExists()
>   #1 {main} thrown in user.php on line 34

Comment: And where do you set `$this->conn`? Show more of your class, please

Comment: `$this->conn` is probably not defined

Comment: `$this->conn` is null which means you failed to create a pdo/mysqli connection.

Comment: You might have to show the full class

Comment: added class Database

Comment: That's the database, but `emailExists` is in your User class, so we'd need to see that.

Comment: ^ (specifically the constructor)

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda show the full user.php class

Comment: PDO doesnt always throw an exception when you connect, for that you need to turn exception mode on with the connection options (sometimes).

Comment: sorry about that.  added the user class.

Comment: `public function _construct($db)`  Do you really have just the single underscore there?

Comment: `_construct($db)` should be `__construct($db)`

Comment: Just an FYI you are creating a new connection every time you call `getConnection()`, you probably want to /should make `public $conn;` static.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't notice that.